# Embed RTSP Stream into Browser

Tags: html, ip, streaming, mp4, rtsp

I have an IP Camera that only has an address locally: XXX.XXX.X.XX.
This camera has an rtsp stream and I want to integrate that stream into HTML5's video tag. Unfortunately, it only accepts mp4, ogg and web. What should I do now?

Note that I do not want to use a plugin!

Comment: You are out of luck, nobody knows how to do that

Comment: I've used ffmpeg to convert the stream on the server, and then serve the new data over websockets.  but it takes up a ton of memory